# Getting error when calling clone method on Singleton object

Tags: java, singleton, cloning

Why do I get an error when calling the clone method on a Singleton object?

This is my Singleton class:

```
public class Singleton  {
    private Singleton (){
    }
    private static Singleton singleton;
    public static Singleton getSingleton(){
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new Singleton();
                    return singleton;
        }
        return singleton;
    }

}
```

This is a user-defined class calling the clone method on the Singleton object:

```
public class SingletonDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Singleton s = Singleton.getSingleton();
        Singleton s1 = (Singleton)s.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give more information on this. What is it that you are trying to do, why do you even want to clone a singleton (If you want to clone it, you aren't using it correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You have not implemented `Cloneable`  hence you will get an exception if you try to clone your class. You should override `clone()` too.

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html):

> Invoking Object's clone method on an instance that does not implement the `Cloneable` interface results in the exception `CloneNotSupportedException` being thrown.

Please also heed the [advice in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675786/getting-error-when-calling-clone-method-on-singleton-object/17676473#comment25749097_17675786) - cloning a singleton invalidates the purpose of having one in the first place. In fact, the moment you clone it it's no longer a singleton.

As a general rule (*not* applying to singletons), consider a copy constructor instead of cloning.